# Remove the following Gaps between two rows when using css Grid as to show 3 colums by sided by side

Tags: html, css, grid

I was building the catalog menus. Here I want to remove the following gaps between two rows.
[The CSS Catalog I have designed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chVCF.png)
And show them As like below,
[The CSS Catalog I want to design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFPKb.png). My CSS Code

```
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30.5% 30.5% 30.5%;
    column-gap: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved. I have updated the divs CSS that contains the lists,

```
{
  column-gap: 40px;
  column-count: 3;
  display: list-item; 
}
```